# jQuery: Delay a mouseenter event (dropdown menu)

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, mouseenter

I'm working on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8n2TQ/9/

It consists of a rollover button which drops down a menu like so:

```
$('#one').mouseenter(function() {

    //Slide down

});
```

The event happens immediately on hover, but I want to put in a small delay to prevent accidental hovers from triggering the event. I tried to work with a timer (see http://jsfiddle.net/8n2TQ/13/) but that doesn't seem to execute all the events under '//Slide up'. I guess I'm missing something here, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check out hoverIntent: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: I came across the plugin but can it handle custom functions? If so how?

Comment: I see, it is indeed possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent

There is a plugin for this that works well.

Answer (score 2):

You asked how to handle function. There is an example on thé plugin page

```
var config = {    
     over: makeTall, // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
     timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
     out: makeShort // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
};

$("#demo3 li").hoverIntent( config )
```